# Devise - Authentication of a User using a non-unique field

Tags: authentication, devise

Currently, we authenticate Users based on their Email field. However, this field is not unique. The main problem is that we should only be allowing access to Users based on the user_type field on the Users table. If there's 2 entries with the same Email but different user_type, we want Devise to attempt signin using the one with user_type = 'Admin'.

Is there a way to restrict the Devise authentication to only look at Users which have user_type = 'Admin' and not other ones?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions to my problem

The first I came up with on my own and that was to simply create a subclass of the User model called AdminUser with a default scope that only allowed user_type = 'admin'

```
class AdminUsers < User
  default_scope { where(user_type: 'admin') }
end
```

Then I just updated the routes.rb file to use that model instead of User

```
devise_for(
  :users,
  class_name: 'AdminUser',
  path:       'auth',
  controllers: {
    sessions: 'authentications',
    passwords: 'passwords'
  }
)
```

This works fine. The only small thing is that now the current_user returns an instance of AdminUser instead of User. I couldn't guarantee that this wouldn't cause issues in some cases.

The second solution was from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

I added this method that overwrites one of Devises internal ones to the User model.

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  where(warden_conditions).where("user_type = 'agent'").first
end
```

The second solution appears to work perfectly.